# Check if number is prime in class constructor?

Tags: typescript, function, class, types

I would like to check when instantiating a object if the input are valid or not (prime); within the `constructor` parameters of the class. How would I accomplish this in typescript? I have already created a lambda and static function for checking if a variable is prime, which one would be best to use in the constructor method? Here is my code:

```
class RSA {

    public check = (n: number) => {
        if (n <= 1)
            return false;
        var i: number = 2;
        while(i*i <= n) 
            n%i == 0 ? false : i += 1;
        return n;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new RSA object
     * @param p 
     * @param q 
     * @returns object capable of encryption/decryption
     */
    constructor(p: number, q: number) {
        this.generateKeys(p, q);
    }

    /**
     * Returns boolean to verify if 'n' is prime 
     * @param n input to verify (e.g. p and q)
     * @returns boolean of n
     */
    public static isPrime(n: number): number | boolean {
        if (n <= 1)
            return false;
        var i: number = 2;
        while(i*i <= n) 
            n%i == 0 ? false : i += 1;
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want `constructor(p: number, q: number) {` to constrain the arguments to be prime, or do you mean you want to carry out the `isPrime` check inside the constructor in JavaScript? And `generateKeys` looks to be missing

Comment: I want the constructor to constrain arguments to be prime. I've removed generateKeys as it is not relevant and wish to not bloat the code.

Comment: Wait, you want someone writing typescript code to receive a compiler warning if the number passed in is not prime? Like, before runtime?  Or do you want a runtime error if someone passes in a nonprime to the constructor? The former is bonkers but I bet it’s “possible” (if you only like supporting numbers up to about 1000 or maybe 100000) and if you like bogging down the compiler), while the latter is easy enough but involves calling `isPrime` inside the constructor which you said you don’t want.  I’m fascinated but scared.